# Using a foreach statement to populate a dropdown list - it display as a single string

Tags: php

When populating a dropdown list using a foreach statement on array, it display a single item as a string.  however, it can populate the list correctly using this syntax ["test1","test2"]

```php
foreach($dataNew[$i]['message'] as $x => $item){
     $myMessage[]='"'.$item['Lots'].'"';
}

$lots=[implode (',', $myMessage)];//does not work
//$lots=['4342355555555@1', '32335455@5'];//works fine
$dataNew[$i]=['Lots'=>[$lots]];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you are creating a php array with your use of [] when you want a string. `$lots=implode (',', $myMessage);`

Comment: Yes, but I implode the array to get the string values which is where things seem to go wrong.

Comment: `["test1","test2"]` is shorthand syntax for `array("test1","test2")`, so just adding `$item['lots']`should work, your commented line is an array: `$lots[]=$item['Lots'];`

Comment: but the implode is inside [] so its an array: http://ideone.com/rqdNVo

Comment: That code is a mess. What is your input and what do you expect from the code?

Comment: @Snakins please consider explaining the context, the purpose and the desired in- and outputs, so we can understand your problem and can help you - sometimes there is an other much better way to be found then... Especialy: explain the use and purpose of the [,] brackets

Comment: @Snakins did my answer help u?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of corrext concatination, assuming some details of your problem, which are not quite clear by now.

Assuming: the `$dataNew` parameter holds an array of strings at `[$i]['message']` which contains lots, which are seperated by commas, and come from some statistical process.

The output shall be an two-dimensional array, which merges all lots of one iteration into one list. So the reslut is a list of lists of lots (foreach `$i`).

```
$currentLotsList = $dataNew[$i]['message'];

//iterating over the lots of the current sample - which are a chain of strings seperated by commas
foreach($currentLotsList as $csvLots){ 
    //getting the lots into an array
    $currentLotsArray = explode(",", $csvLots); 

    //adding this list to the major list of $i, 
    if(!isset($dataNew[$i]['Lots']) ){

        //createing the array if not set now.
        $dataNew[$i]['Lots'] = [];
    }

     $dataNew[$i]['Lots'] = array_merge($dataNew[$i]['Lots'], $currentLotsArray); 
}
```